# Android MaterialButton style not changing

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I am trying to style the material buttons using the new styles offered by the `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`
 library. The issue is that the buttons are not styling properly. For example, I have 2 different activities using the exact same theme, with the exact same code for the button but on refuses to use the right style, on the Android preview screen it looks right but in the actual app its not.

Also, I am manually overriding the style of a group of buttons by setting `style="myButtonStyleWhatever"` but that just gets ignored as well. This is getting very frustrating so I would love if someone could help.

**Styles-v11**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#364c70</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WhiteButtons" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:background">#ffff</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Styles-v21**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Styles**

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#364c70</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WhiteButtons" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:background">#ffff</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Code used for the button**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/get_suggestions"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_65sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="163dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="163dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="219dp"
            android:text="SEARCH"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp"
            app:cornerRadius="100dp" />
```

**Not meant to look like that**

[image]

```
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/xmlns:app="
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragger"
sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/dragView">

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">




            <com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_233sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_58sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:elevation="100dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                sothree:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                sothree:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:id="@+id/get_suggestions"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_65sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cornerRadius="100dp"
                android:text="SEARCH"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp"
                sothree:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                sothree:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



            <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/mapview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="46.885"
                mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="24.679"
                mapbox:mapbox_cameraTilt="20"
                mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="4"

mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="mapbox://styles/sudafly/cjm89d4011nu02smk5a7e0d8h"
                sothree:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                sothree:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                sothree:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                sothree:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

     <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        />

  </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>






  <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dragView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:background="#2a2e41"
        android:id="@+id/dragger"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/search_for_airports"
            android:textColor="#d2d4e0"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drag"
        android:background="#eceff1">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Lin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#eceff1"
                android:elevation="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="0dp">


                    <include layout="@layout/charts_v2" />

                    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

The styles you've posted don't make a ton of sense.

- You are showing `ToolBarStyle` and `WhiteButtons` styles but you're not using them anywhere.
- You have `MyMaterialTheme` (as opposed to `MyMaterialTheme.Base`) in one of the files; I hope you aren't expecting this to be automatically inherited from by `MyMaterialTheme.Base`, since specifying a `parent` overrides the dot-notation inheritance.
- All three files have the same contents for `MyMaterialTheme.Base`; why bother specifying it in three places?

Additionally, none of the styles you've posted seem like they would affect `MaterialButton` widgets (except for `colorPrimary`). So it's hard to know exactly where your problem lies.

All that said, the list of attributes supported by `MaterialButton` is available in [the GitHub documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#attributes). Notably, `android:background` is **not** supported by `MaterialButton`. From [the JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton):

> Do not use the `android:background` attribute. `MaterialButton` manages its own background drawable, and setting a new background means `MaterialButton` can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it introduces will function properly. If the default background is changed, `MaterialButton` cannot guarantee well-defined behavior.

I suspect that what you're seeing is a combination of different `colorPrimary` definitions on the two screens and the fact that `android:background` is not supported.

If you want to manually override the button's background color, use the `app:backgroundTint` attribute on your `<MaterialButton>` tag. If you want to specify that in a `<style>` tag, it doesn't use a namespace:

```
<item name="backgroundTint">@color/your_background_color</item>
```

Comment: Thanks I will make some changes but I'm using "style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" for one of my buttons and it doesn't actually look like it's meant to

Comment: In the android preview it uses the "outline" style but on the device it looks like in the picture

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've posted that explains why the `OutlinedButton` style wouldn't work. The relevant information is the AndroidManifest.xml `<activity>` entry for the activity your button is in, the `<style>` definition for the theme your activity is using, and the full layout xml that your button is included inside of (so that we can see if any parent views might be affecting it) as well as any `<style>` definitions used by any parent of your `<MaterialButton>` tag in the layout.

Comment: Also relevant is what device/emulator you're testing on, especially the Android OS version.

Comment: P    `<activity android:name=".DemoActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>` for the activity. I am testing it out on a Pixel 2 XL Android P. I updated the post and added the whole XML for the layout. I don't really understand what you mean by <style> definition for the theme..

Comment: Either your `<application>` tag or your `<activity>` tag in the manifest will specify an `android:theme` attribute. This will reference a `<style>` you've defined somewhere, and that would be relevant.

Comment: ohhh. In my `<application>` tag i use     `android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base"`